# Jenkins MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.Switch: Files

Tags: jenkins, tfsbuild, jenkins-build-flow

I know there are many threads with same subject line ,but i am not getting any answer and hence putting my question here.
I am new to this and try to learn as fast as possible due to the time lines i have.
I did Jenkin setup (tried my best to do correctly in first shot)
But when ever i try to build  i got following error

```
Started by user User 1
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\********Service
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Querying for remote changeset at '$/Reference Data Master/Development/Source/*******DataSrvices' as of 'D2017-08-24T07:21:11Z'...
Query result is: Changeset #109084 by 'user' on '2017-08-23T13:04:44Z'.
Checking if there exists a mapping for E:\MyDrive\Jenkins\workspace...yes, in workspace 'Hudson-*****Service-MASTER'.
Downloading list of workspaces from http://********:8080/tfs...
Getting version 'C109084' to 'E:\MyDrive\Jenkins\workspace'...
Finished getting version 'C109084'. Retrieved 0 resources.
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 && C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe %workspace%\DataService.Windows\DataSrvices.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\WindowsService
[WindowsService] $ cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 && C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe %workspace%\DataService.Windows\DataSrvices.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Active code page: 1252
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.34209
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Files

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please find the setup i did for my first JOB in jenkins

Source COde managment : Done it for TFS

[image]

Build Trigger

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to pass Command Line Arguments with some switches like visual studio version, target etc...

Comment: any example to start

Answer (score 0):

Use the MSBuild plugin, and simply build your complete solution.  The example in this screen shot even runs your code analysis if you like.
[image: MSBuild]